# Inserting an image to a particular position in a word document using docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

I want to add an image to particular position in my  word document using docx4j. I don't want inline insertion. The code below performs adding the image inline with text. But I want floating insertion where I can explicitly give the location of where the image should be placed in the page. Please help me.

```
    public R addUserPic(P parag, WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage)
                throws Exception {

            File file = new File("src/main/resources/PictureNew.png");
            byte[] bytes = convertImageToByteArray(file);   
            BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart = BinaryPartAbstractImage
                    .createImagePart(wordMLPackage, bytes);
            int docPrId = 1;
            int cNvPrId = 2;

            Inline inline = imagePart.createImageInline("Filename hint",
                    "Alternative text", docPrId, cNvPrId, false);   

            ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
            R run = factory.createR();
            org.docx4j.wml.Drawing drawing = factory.createDrawing();
            run.getContent().add(drawing);
            drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(inline);

            return run;

        }

        private static byte[] convertImageToByteArray(File file)
                throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            long length = file.length();

            if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                System.out.println("File too large!!");
            }
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
            int offset = 0;
            int numRead = 0;
            while (offset < bytes.length
                    && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
                offset += numRead;
            }

            if (offset < bytes.length) {
                System.out.println("Could not completely read file "
                        + file.getName());
            }
            is.close();
            return bytes;


}
```

Comment: How have you attempted to do this in docx4?

Comment: yes.. i have tried it in inline way.. but i want to place the image in any given position in the document

Comment: I asked how not what. The subtle difference is that the latter was already answered in your question and the former requests the code you have written so far to get an understanding of what you may be doing wrong or how you may be incorrectly approaching the problem. It also expects that you have done some work of your own on the problem and didn't just come here asking for some canned code to paste into your project.

Answer (score 1):

The thread you have cross posted in, at http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/how-to-create-a-floating-image-t1224.html answers your question.